# How to Implement CheckBoxFor in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to understand how to use CheckBoxFor in MVC 5. I'm new to MVC and trying to learn how Entity Framework works using code first migrations.
Here are my main class Request:

```
[KeyAttribute] //One solution said to add this. Made no difference.
public virtual Guid ID { get; set; }


[Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required.")] [Display(Name = "First Name:")] [StringLength(25, ErrorMessage = "First Name must not exceed 25 characters.")]
public virtual string FName { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Middle Initial:")] [StringLength(1, ErrorMessage = "Middle Initial must not exceed 1 character.")]
public virtual string MI { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required.")] [Display(Name = "Last Name:")] [StringLength(25, ErrorMessage = "Last Name must not exceed 25 characters.")]
public virtual string LName { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Date of Birth is required.")] [Display(Name = "Date of Birth:")]
public virtual DateTime DOB { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required.")] [Display(Name = "Email:")] [StringLength(25, ErrorMessage = "Email must not exceed 50 characters.")]
public virtual string Email { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone Number is required.")] [Display(Name = "Phone Number")] [StringLength(14, ErrorMessage = "Phone number must not exceed 14 characters.")]
public virtual string Phone { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone Type selection is required.")] [Display(Name = "Phone Type:")] [StringLength(4, ErrorMessage = "Phone Type selection must not exceed 4 characters.")]
public virtual string PhoneType { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Preferred Contact Method selection is required.")] [Display(Name = "Preferred Contact Method:")] [StringLength(16, ErrorMessage = "Preferred Contact Method selection must not exceed 16 characters.")]
public virtual PrefContactViewModel PrefContactViewModel {get;set;}

[Display(Name = "Preferred Contact Time:")] [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Preferred Contact Time must not exceed 50 characters.")]
public virtual string PrefContactTime { get; set; }
...
```

Here is my ViewModel PrefContactViewModel:

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public bool Checked { get; set; }
```

Here is my controller RequestsController Index Action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var requests = db.Requests.Include(r => r.PrefContactViewModel);
    return View(requests.ToList());
}
```

Here is the same controller RequestForm Action:

```
public ActionResult RequestForm()
{
    return View();
}
```

And here is my View:

```
@model AMYA.Models.Request
<div class="opensans margin-sides">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <hr />

                //FIRST NAME, MIDDLE INITIAL, LAST NAME
    <div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-5">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })<span class="red">*</span>
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MI, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MI, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-5">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })<span class="red">*</span>
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

                //DATE OF BIRTH, EMAIL, PHONE NUMBER, PHONE TYPE
    <div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DOB, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })<span class="red">*</span>
            <div class="">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DOB, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })<span class="red">*</span>
            <div class="">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })<span class="red">*</span>
            <div class="">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })<span class="red">*</span>
            <div class="">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.PrefContactViewModel.Checked, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="PrefContact" name="PrefContact" value="@Request["PrefContact"]" />
                    @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PrefContact, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "checkbox" } })*@
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.PrefContactViewModel.Checked, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PrefContactTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div class="">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PrefContactTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
...
```

I just need to create a checkbox for each of the Name fields in my RequestForm Action. I've tried several of the solutions found here and elsewhere, but I cannot get the CheckBoxFor to work.

Can anyone offer me some insight into how to get CheckBoxFor to populate with the four selections? Or is there a way to do this using regular HTML `<input>` field?

And I get the following in my View:
[image]

Comment: `CheckBoxFor` has nothing to do with Entity Framework. Also, ASP.NET MVC 5 is obsolete (it's the last version of ASP.NET MVC before ASP.NET Core came out). Is there a reason you're not using ASP.NET Core for new projects?

Comment: I tried to go that route, but was out voted. My clients want me to use MVC.

Comment: I just noticed that you're not actually presenting a list - you're representing each field as a list - why are you doing that instead of using normal properties for each field? Is this a user-customizable form?

Comment: @NMeneses You do know that ASP.NET Core includes MVC Core in it? ASP.NET and MVC 5 should not be used for any new development.

Answer (score 0):

(**Update:** I wrote this answer before I realised that the OP was using the `List<>` where each list item is its own **field** (i.e. as runtime customizable form builder) instead of representing each form field as a view-model class property, and this answer is not entire suitable for that scenario - but using `EditorFor` rather than `CheckBoxFor` should still work in this case).

You can't use an `IEnumerable<T>` as the static-type for a View's `@model` because ASP.NET model-binding (when repopulating the Model from the POST request body) works with `List<T>`, not `IEnumerable<T>`.

To use model-binding with a `List<T>` you need to use a `for( int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++ )`-style loop, you cannot use a `foreach`-style loop because it doesn't expose the item's index for use with the `List<T>`'s indexer property (okay, you can technically use `foreach` with `.Select( (e, idx) => ... )` but it only results in more unproductive keyboard typing.

1. Change your ViewModel to its own class rather than directly exposing a `List<T>` anyway, because it makes everything else easier (such as adding a page title or other non-list content to the page).
2. Use a `for()` loop to render each item.
3. Your `@model` line must match the actual `model` object passed into `View(Object)`.

Like so:

#### Controller action:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    // this is an example of an additional non-list-item property you'd add to the viewmodel:
    [BindNever] // this is a one-way (server-to-client) property, so use [BindNever]
    public String PageTitle { get; internal set; }

    [Required]
    public List<PrefContactViewModel> MyList { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult RequestForm()
{
    MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel()
    {
        PageTitle = "My list page!",
        MyList = new List<PrefContactViewModel>
        {
             new PrefContactViewModel { ID = 1, Name = "Call", Checked = false },
             new PrefContactViewModel { ID = 2, Name = "Text", Checked = false },
             new PrefContactViewModel { ID = 3, Name = "Email", Checked = false },
             new PrefContactViewModel { ID = 4, Name = "Traditional Mail", Checked = false },
        }
    };

    return View( vm );
}
```

#### Your view:

```
@model MyViewModel
<div class="opensans margin-sides">
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

    <h1>@this.Model.PageTitle</h1>

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <hr />

    @for( int i = 0; i < this.Model.MyList.Count; i++ ) {

        <!-- HTML markup removed for readability -->

        @Html.LabelFor( m => m.MyList[i].FName )
        @Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.MyList[i].FName )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor( m => m.MyList[i].FName )


        @** Checkboxes should be wrapped in a <label> rather than using a separate label so you can't use @LabelFor **@
        <label>@Html.CheckBoxFor( m => m.MyList[i].Checked ) @Html.DisplayNameFor( m => m.MyList[i].Checked )</label>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor( m => m.MyList[i].Checked )

        @** etc for other members of each list item **@

    } @** for loop **@
} @** </form> **@
```

Comment: But don't I need my first model Request to populate the other fields... Name, MI, Last Name, etc? I know I can't use two models in one view, so how does the View see my first Model to populate the other input fields?